# Обучение (адаптация) Microsoft Speech SDK 11

Tags: распознавание-речи, microsoft-speech-sdk

Пишу программу, использующую Microsoft Speech SDK 11.

Подскажите способы ПРОГРАММНОГО обучения (адаптации) Microsoft Speech API, через код.

Необходимо обучить ее распознавать конкретную фразу (обучить ее для лучшего распознавания конкретной фразы).

Мне не подходит вариант обучения `System.Speech.Recognition`, через "Панель Управления" => "Распознавание Речи".